# XCode project is locked by unknown reason, and show a giant lock icon on storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I just start implement Auto Resize with tick the option box. It is fine at the beginning. After few hours leaning and playing with auto resize and Debug View Hierarchy. My project start show this lock:
[image: Locked Xcode]

And, I can't do anything on the XCode. Even the drop down menu doesn't responding my clicks. I can slowly move stroyboard view with dramatically delay.

Anyone met same problem? How can I solve this?

Comment: Download a trial version of AppCode and open the project. It will probably be able to snare you out of this. Caution : after a month it will cost you a license, don't get to like it too much.

Comment: @Yi Jiang, Did you find any solution for this?  I m facing the same issue on 7.3 xcode for one my older project.

Comment: @Ameer Sorry, It takes too long to remember. I never get this issue after that for years.